# What part of my SQL query is wrong?

Tags: sql-server

Part of SQL Server database entities are:

- Forms (Id, Counter)
- Groups (Id, Form_Id, Counter)
- Fields (Id, Group_Id, Counter)

The logic of this structure is:

- Fields counter can be 0 or higher
- The groups counter depends on the counters of fields that exist in this group: every field's counter value that is higher than 0 increments the group counter by one
- The same relation exists between group and form: form's counter is the sum of the group's counters that are higher than 0

A little example for best understanding:

```
Form A1 (Counter: 1)
|-> Group BB1 (Counter: 2)
   |-> Field CCC1 (Counter: 2)
   |-> Field CCC2 (Counter: 1)
|-> Group BB2 (Counter: 0)
   |-> Field CCC3 (Counter: 0)
   |-> Field CCC4 (Counter: 0)
Form A2
...
```

Some fields contains invalid values that my query need to check. But I can't write it in right way. The last version of it:

```
    select distinct
        cd.Id as [FormID],
        sum (case when cd.Counter > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.Id, gd.Id, fd.Id) as [FormSum],
        cd.Counter as [FormVal],

        gd.Id as [GroupID],
        sum(case when gd.Counter > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.Id, gd.Id, fd.Id) as [GroupSum],
        gd.Counter as [GroupVal],

        fd.Id as [FieldID],
        --sum(case when fd.Counter > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cd.Id, gd.Id) as [FieldSum],
        fd.Counter as [FieldVal]
    from FieldDatas fd
    inner join GroupDatas gd on fd.GroupData_Id = gd.Id
    inner join CrfDatas cd on gd.CrfData_Id = cd.Id
    where cd.Id in
    (
        -- some subquery
    )
    order by cd.Id, gd.Id, fd.Id
```

**Update:**
This query needs to compare saved Counters data in all entities with query-calculated values, and fix these values in future.

Will be happy for any help.

Comment: ddl and sample data along with a clear explanation of what you want your query to do would go a long way towards getting you an answer. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the contents of two tables with a single query, so we end up with two UPDATE statements. Next, fix the “lower” relationship (Groups/Fields) before the “upper” one. Steps I took:

First set up test structures and data:

```
--  Set up test tables
CREATE TABLE Forms
(Id  int  not null
,Counter  int  not null)

CREATE TABLE Groups
(Id  int  not null
,Form_id  int  not null
,Counter  int not null)

CREATE TABLE Fields
(Id  int  not null
,Group_Id  int  not null
,Counter  int not null)


--  Set up valid test data
DELETE Forms DELETE Groups DELETE Fields
INSERT Forms values
  (1,1)
INSERT Groups values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,0)
INSERT Fields values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,1)
 ,(3,2,0)
 ,(4,2,0)


--  Set invalid Forms counter
DELETE Forms DELETE Groups DELETE Fields
INSERT Forms values
  (1,2)
INSERT Groups values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,0)
INSERT Fields values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,1)
 ,(3,2,0)
 ,(4,2,0)


--  Set invalid Groups counter (both) 
DELETE Forms DELETE Groups DELETE Fields
INSERT Forms values
  (1,2)
INSERT Groups values
  (1,1,0)
 ,(2,1,1)
INSERT Fields values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,1)
 ,(3,2,0)
 ,(4,2,0)


--  Mondo invalid
DELETE Forms DELETE Groups DELETE Fields
INSERT Forms values
  (1,0)
INSERT Groups values
  (1,1,0)
 ,(2,1,1)
INSERT Fields values
  (1,1,2)
 ,(2,1,1)
 ,(3,2,0)
 ,(4,2,0)
```

Next, identify bad data in the “lower” set:

```
--  Detect bad data in Groups/Fields relationship
SELECT
   gr.Id
  ,gr.Counter
  ,sum(case when fi.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) CalcValue
 from Groups gr
  left outer join Fields fi
   on fi.Group_Id = gr.Id
 group by
   gr.Id
  ,gr.Counter
 having sum(case when fi.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> gr.Counter
```

Use that as a subquery in an update statement:

```
--  Reset invalid Forms counters
UPDATE Groups
 set Counter = xx.CalcValue
 from Groups gr
  inner join (--  Detect bad data in Groups/Fields relationship
              select
                 gr.Id
                ,gr.Counter
                ,sum(case when fi.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) CalcValue
               from Groups gr
                left outer join Fields fi
                 on fi.Group_Id = gr.Id
               group by
                 gr.Id
                ,gr.Counter
               having sum(case when fi.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> gr.Counter) xx
   on xx.Id = gr.Id
```

Cut, paste, rename for the “upper” set:

```
--  Detect bad data in Forms/Groups relationship
SELECT
   fo.Id
  ,fo.Counter
  ,sum(case when gr.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) CalcValue
 from Forms fo
  left outer join Groups gr
   on gr.Form_Id = fo.Id
 group by
   fo.Id
  ,fo.Counter
 having sum(case when gr.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> fo.Counter


--  Reset invalid Forms counters
UPDATE Forms
 set Counter = xx.CalcValue
 from Forms fo
  inner join (--  Detect bad data in Forms/Groups relationship
              select
                 fo.Id
                ,fo.Counter
                ,sum(case when gr.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) CalcValue
               from Forms fo
                left outer join Groups gr
                 on gr.Form_Id = fo.Id
               group by
                 fo.Id
                ,fo.Counter
               having sum(case when gr.Counter <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) <> fo.Counter) xx
   on xx.Id = fo.Id
```

Run just the updates in that order and review the results:

```
SELECT * from Forms
SELECT * from Groups
SELECT * from Fields
```

Assumptions: the data is clean and as described, indexes are properly set if the tables are large, no other unanticipated discrepancies come up.